# Is it possible to reset the privacy settings in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calabash, ekeventkit

In order to test access granting to the iOS calendar, I need to reset the privacy settings on my test device.

However, every time I install it on the device it remembers the old privacy settings and does not show the alert view to ask me if I grant access. Deleting the app and reinstalling it does not change this fact.

Is there a way to make iOS forget it knows my app and ask me again?

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic.  This issue comes up all the time during iOS UI testing.  If the question included 'programmatically' or 'automatically' and include a calabash-ios or uiautomation tag, would it be acceptable?

Comment: This question is not off-topic at all, and it would be a shame if Apple adds a new way to reset permission for a single app, and no one could add a new answer because it's locked.

Comment: This question is not off-topic, it's something app developers need to do at times.

Comment: This is not off topic and maybe it is about time that Stack Overflow 'supervisors' will stop putting people down and restrict good and obviously interesting questions judging by their score.

Comment: @Adi I've voted to reopen this. Hopefully it gets reopened.

Comment: I've edited to add reasons why this is important for devs and why it should not be closed. Hopefully it passes peer review

Comment: This is really a developer issue: The question affects developers/testers who need to understand & test the behavior of an app when the privacy settings are not yet set for the first time. (Deleting & reinstalling the app does not affect the privacy settings.)

Comment: Reworded the question and flagged for reopen.

Comment: This is clearly not off topic in a practical sense, as this is core activity for iOS development, nor is it off topic in a letter of the law sense, as an iOS test device cannot in any way be called general computing hardware for a question tagged as iOS.

Comment: Here a little hack for u guys: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33940858/1415713

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Start the "Settings.app", go to General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy.

This resets the privacy settings for all apps, but as far as I know, there is no way to reset it for a single app. Even removing the app and installing it again does not help.

Comment: This is the same case in iOS 7.

Comment: This is really useful for testing purposes, particularly when trying to test all the edge cases of privacy permissions. Thanks!

Comment: There is a hack way that one of the good guys working with me found - it is a hack, but it works great to reset single application settings if you need for example to test your application for permissions.

Comment: @Adi What is the hack?

Comment: @Adi Yes, what is the hack? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay.   You remove your application, then reset your device (yes total power off and boot).   Now you go the the time / clock and set it to manual and set the date to be at least 1 day ahead - I usually select 2 days to be on the safe side.     Finally after it is all done, you reboot again and install the application - all settings should now be reset.    Unfortunately you need to keep doing it and advance the dayes every time - very tedious.   What is the explanation?   Apparently Apple keeps some sort of consistency data that lasts for 24 hours of activity.   Hope that helps.