# Location Services popup only showing on simulator and not on iOS device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, location

I created a tab based application. On one of my tabs, I have a `UIWebView`. I have a `webpage` in the `UIWebView` that uses location services. I didn't add any additional coding to use location services. When I test my app in the iOS Simulator, there is a popup asking if you want this webpage to use location services. When I test it on an iOS device, no popup comes up asking me if I want to use location services for this webpage.

Comment: Each app asks only once. If you want the popup to re-appear on the device, you have to reset all privacy settings on the device, see for example ["Is it possible to reset the privacy settings in iOS 6?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596165/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-privacy-settings-in-ios-6).

Comment: To the editor of the question: The back ticks are for **code** . Marking all keywords such as `webpage`, `iOS Simulator`, `location services` as code does not (in my opinion) increase the readability.