# Delete iOS app settings

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm working on an app that requires requesting mail access. Since the simulator doesn't have a Mail app I've been using my physical device to test the app.

My problem is that I want to test the request to access Mail in relation to the welcome/intro screen that I've made but even if I delete the Xcode build version of the app from my device the settings for allowing the Mail access still persist.

I want to force those settings to delete when I delete my app from the device so that it requests Mail access after every fresh install for the sake of testing. So far the only solution that I've seen for doing this is to complete a fresh install of iOS each time, but that's much to much trouble when I'd be wanting to do it several times.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596165/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-privacy-settings-in-ios.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator does actually have a Calendar and I do plenty of testing on it.  If you want to add more calendars via the simulator, open the calendar app, tap edit at the top and you can enter new calendars.

Comment: My mistake. I was confusing mail app with calendar app. Simulator does have a calendar app, but no mail app. My question still stands for how to solve the issue on a physical device though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found thanks to @Martin R's comment.

Go to General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

This reset accomplished what I needed for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've myself run into the same problem when allowing photo access.

It's not a proper answer, but the workaround I found was effective: just change the bundle id when you want to test this behaviour. iOS will assume it's a different app and ask you again for all the authorisations granted before.

I'm still interested by the proper answer though — if there ever is one.

Comment: Proper answer is the one linked to by @Martin-R (which btw I more accurately reworded and voted to reopen). I will nevertheless leave my answer here in the hope that it might still be of use to somebody.