# iOS Local Notifications: app is not asking for permissions to notify the user

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am not sure if this is a weird bug, but in my

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

I have the following lines of code to ask for user permissions:

```
// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

On the simulator, everything works fine, but on my iPhone, when I install the app, it does not ask for these permissions. I have initiated breakpoints to make sure the lines execute and they do.

When I go into `Settings > Notifications > My App` the notifications are on, so it seems that the system knows I have granted permission before, so it doesn't ask, but that seems weird.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the App from your device and the install it again to reset everything ?

Comment: I assume that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596165/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-privacy-settings-in-ios applies here as well: you have to reset the privacy settings (or change the time on the device and reboot as explained in a comment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found the answer after Googling again (I didn't find the answer before)

Straight from Apple:

> Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS The first
>   time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the
>   user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user
>   has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the
>   device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> 1. Delete your app from the device.
> 2. Turn the device off completely and
>      turn it back on.
> 3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the
>      date ahead a day or more.
> 4. Turn the device off completely again and
>      turn it back on.

After doing this, asking for permission worked again.

Comment: "has been uninstalled for at least a day" i wonder what twisted logic apple used to come up with that. Deleting the app should remove notification decision. Thanks for this clarification