# requestAccessForEntityType not prompting user

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, contacts

I am trying to gain access to the phone's contacts with the code below but the user isn't prompted to give me permission.

```
 let store = CNContactStore()
        store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) { granted, error in
            guard granted else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    // user didn't grant authorization, so tell them to fix that in settings
                    print("error accessing adress book %@",error)
                }
                return
            }
            print("Access granted to adress book")
            // get the contacts

            var contacts = [CNContact]()
            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName)])
            do {
                try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request) { contact, stop in
                    contacts.append(contact)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            //TODO : Do something with the contacts
            let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
            formatter.style = .FullName
            for contact in contacts {
                print(formatter.stringFromContact(contact))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate what is the exact error?

I tried your code on a iOS 9.2.1 device and the code seems to be working fine. I got the "Access granted to adress book" log and the contacts information.

You should check device permission at Setings->Privacy->Contacts, if you are facing Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=100 "Access Denied" error.

Just in case, if you clicked "Dont Allow" on the Contact access permission prompt and now as the preference has got saved and you are not getting the prompt, then you can change your bundle identifier to test your code.

If you need to reset all privacy settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12596350/4209778